# jetty error starting on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, jetty

Hello Ive downloaded jetty and whenever I try to start it it generate the following log and gives an error so I can't use it, can somebody tell me whats wrong or whats missing

Im starting on terminal in the bin folder with the "./jetty.sh start"

Here's the error on localhost:8080

Error 404 - Not Found.

No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
Powered by Jetty Java Web Server

Heres the log:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6j7t1lhqscv34l/log.rtf

Comment: From the exception, it looks like you already have something listening on port 8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that port 8080 is already in use: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use 
"

Try an different port or don't declare a port and use logic like this to figure out what you are bound to:
Server server = new Server(0);

int port =  ((ServerConnector) server.getConnectors()[0]).getLocalPort();